# PL/SQL Trigger to sum rows and update other rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I tried to do the following:

> Write a trigger such that the budget of a department is the sum of salaries paid to employees in the department (remember employees work only a percent of time in a department). The **DEPT** table includes Dept ID (Did), Budget, ManagerID, the **Employee(EMP)** table includes EMPID(eid), SALARY, BONUS, AGE, and the **WORKS** table includes eid, Did, working_time.

The code I wrote was:

```
CREATE TRIGGER BUDGET_CHK
BEFORE
    INSERT OR UPDATE OF BUDGET OR DELETE ON DEPT
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       UPDATE DEPT
       SET BUDGET = 
       (SELECT SUM(E.SALARY)
       FROM EMP E, WORKS W, DEPT D
       WHERE E.eid=W.eid AND D.did=W.did
       GROUP BY W.did)
    END;
```

I am new to oracle. Can someone correct me on this? Thanks!

Errors (from comments below):

```
pl/sql: sql statement ignored

ORA-00933 sql command not properly ended

Error(16): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
  one of the following: ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if
  loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier>
  <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> << continue close
  current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute
  commit forall merge pipe purge
```

Comment: What's the problem with existing?

Comment: The compiler responded me with errors

Comment: 'pl/sql: sql statement ignored'
'ORA-00933 sql command not properly ended.'

Comment: 'Error(16): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in one spot.

1. You missed ";" symbol after UPDATE statement - this is the technical error.
2. Your UPDATE statement changes ALL rows in DEPT table - I don't think this is that you expect.
3. Your subquery can return more than 1 row - this means you will get "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row" runtime error
   Probably you want something like:

   ```
    UPDATE DEPT D  
    SET BUDGET =   
        (SELECT SUM(E.SALARY)  
         FROM EMP E, WORKS W  
         WHERE E.eid=W.eid   
         AND D.did=W.did)  
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *  
                  FROM EMP E, WORKS W  
                  WHERE E.eid=W.eid   
                  AND D.did=W.did  
    );
   ```
4. You create row-level trigger on DEP table and try to change DEPT table inside the body - you should learn about "mutating table problem": http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936
5. In the multiuser environment when several transactions can change data in tables
   your code will get irrelevant results due to transaction isolation. Please learn Oracle concepts: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm

Comment: You make good points, but this is clearly a homework assignment, so advice about programming in the real world is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_trigger before

  INSERT OR UPDATE OF budget ON dept 

  FOR EACH row 

  declare

  l_budget NUMBER;

  BEGIN

    SELECT SUM(sal) INTO l_budget

    FROM employees e

    INNER JOIN works w

    ON w.eid       =e.eid;

    IF :new.budget < l_budget THEN

      raise_application_error(-20001,'Out of budget');

    END IF;

  END;
```

From Your description it might work.